# How to add svg icons to Swatch attribute (disable admin panel file validation)?

Tags: attributes, magento2.3, swatches, svg

Currently, I can load png/jpg files in swatch attribute, but when I tried to load save attribute with loaded svg file, it's not working. When I load svg from servers - it displays well, but when I tried to add svg file through the admin panel - it's not work.
[image: Swatch attribute]

Answer (score 1):

By default, Magento does not allow SVG file uploads for security reasons. I strongly recommend against enabling SVG uploads for security purposes. However, if you still wish to enable SVG uploads, you can follow the steps below:

Create a di.xml file in your custom module:

Location: **app/code/MyCompany/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml**

Add a preference for the swatch controller within the di.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Swatches\Controller\Adminhtml\Iframe\Show" type="MyCompany\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Iframe\Show" />
</config>
```

Create a new controller in the following location:
**MyCompany\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Iframe\Show.php**
In the Show.php controller file, use the following code:

```
<?php
namespace MyCompany\ModuleName\Controller\Adminhtml\Iframe;

class Show extends \Magento\Swatches\Controller\Adminhtml\Iframe\Show
{
    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $uploader = $this->uploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'datafile']);
            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png', 'svg']);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\AdapterInterface $imageAdapter */
            // $imageAdapter = $this->adapterFactory->create();
            // $uploader->addValidateCallback('catalog_product_image', $imageAdapter, 'validateUploadFile');
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
            /** @var \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\Read $mediaDirectory */
            $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $config = $this->config;
            $result = $uploader->save($mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($config->getBaseTmpMediaPath()));
            unset($result['path']);

            $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
                'swatch_gallery_upload_image_after',
                ['result' => $result, 'action' => $this]
            );

            unset($result['tmp_name']);

            $result['url'] = $this->config->getTmpMediaUrl($result['file']);
            $result['file'] = $result['file'] . '.tmp';

            $newFile = $this->swatchHelper->moveImageFromTmp($result['file']);
            //$this->swatchHelper->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
            $fileData = ['swatch_path' => $this->swatchHelper->getSwatchMediaUrl(), 'file_path' => $newFile];
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($fileData));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $result = ['error' => $e->getMessage(), 'errorcode' => $e->getCode()];
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($result));
        }
    }
}
```

Please make sure to adapt the code to your specific module and customization needs. Enabling SVG uploads should be done with caution, as it may pose security risks.